# Can i use FaunaDB for Offline-First Apps?

Tags: database, synchronization, offline, faunadb

FaunaDB is a new serverless database provider with some cool features. Unfortunately, my Google search did not reveal whether FaunaDB can also be used for offline-first apps. Currently I am developing a webapp with Svelte and a mobile app with React Native. I need a local and a server side database as for synchronisation. I have already seen approaches like RXDB, but these are local databases.

So my question: Can I use FaunaDB also for offline apps, or can I somehow use solutions like RXDB together with Fauna?

Answer (score 2):

Fauna is a data API that lives in the cloud. It is not a library for local database functions.

For developers, you can run a local Docker image. For more details, see https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/integrations/dev

You'd likely need to create your own abstraction layer to make your app's data access agnostic to your online/offline status.